# Open new window through Javascript

Tags: javascript, new-window

I have some simple code to open reddit, but i need it to open in a new window.
tried some different approaches but can't get any to work. Any idea what to add to below code?

```
<a href="http://www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location); return false"><img src="http://www.reddit.com/static/spreddit7.gif" alt="submit to reddit" border="0" /></a>
```

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk the target attribute is deprecated since HTML5

Comment: @line-o So what's the non-Javascript alternative to `target="_blank"`?

Comment: there is none - the client is to decide where to open a link

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.open("http://www.reddit.com/submit?url="+encodeURIComponent(window.location))
```

Check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for further information

Answer (score 0):

You obviously want to suppress the standard link behaviour by adding

```
return false;
```

to the onclick handler.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('url');return false;">label</a>
```

Consider putting that logic in a separate click handling function

```
function handleClick(evt) {
   var url = '' // build your url here
   window.open(url);
   evt.target.preventDefault();
}
```

And add it to your link with

```
element.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

Comment: there has to be an easier way without altering/adding all this though?

Comment: Honestly, lowercase, you can't make the old proverbial omelette without breaking a few eggs.  Perhaps it would be best to have a bit of a read up on JavaScript to see what it can do.

Comment: I'm not sure the point of this site is for me to go away and read up on javascript. If only I had the time. Thanks for your efforts though.